# Jetty WebsocketClient does not connect with SSL on android

Tags: java, android, ssl, websocket, jetty

I have a problem and any help is appreciated. My test device is an ASUS Nexus 7 Android 5.1. I want to connect to a webserver using Jetty Websockets. The url is using wss and I have edited the internet permission in the manifest.xml file. Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 10.07.2015.
 */
public class Socket extends WebSocketAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLogger(Socket.class);

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
        super.onWebSocketConnect(session);
        LOG.info("onConnect({})", session);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
        super.onWebSocketText(message);
        LOG.info("onMessage() - {}", message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);
        LOG.info("onClose({}, {})", statusCode, reason);

    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
        super.onWebSocketError(cause);
        LOG.warn(cause);
    }
}
```

This is the websocket class. I am starting the websocket client in the MainActivity of my android app:

```
URI uri = URI.create("wss://localhost:8600");
        SslContextFactory ssl = new SslContextFactory();
        ssl.setTrustAll(true);
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(ssl);

        try {
            client.start();
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            Future<Session> fut = client.connect(socket, uri);
        } catch (Throwable t) {

            LOG.warn(t);
        }
```

After compiling the logger shows the following errors, from which I assume that the server can't connect to the server.

```
07-11 16:23:50.175  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ Defaulting Uptime to NOIMPL due to (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) Implementation not available in this environment
07-11 16:23:50.201  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ 2015-07-11 16:23:50.200:INFO::main: Logging initialized @-1ms
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ 2015-07-11 16:23:50.450:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED SslContextFactory@da9981a(null,null): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.customize(SslContextFactory.java:1382)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.newSSLEngine(SslContextFactory.java:1328)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:309)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.doStart(WebSocketClient.java:256)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.example.khodor.simplechatneuerversuch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 16:23:50.451  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ 2015-07-11 16:23:50.452:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient@25ca86c5: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.customize(SslContextFactory.java:1382)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.newSSLEngine(SslContextFactory.java:1328)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:309)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.doStart(WebSocketClient.java:256)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.example.khodor.simplechatneuerversuch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-11 16:23:50.452  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ 2015-07-11 16:23:50.453:WARN:ceks.MainActivity:main:
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.customize(SslContextFactory.java:1382)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.newSSLEngine(SslContextFactory.java:1328)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:309)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.doStart(WebSocketClient.java:256)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.example.khodor.simplechatneuerversuch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-11 16:23:50.453  10167-10167/programmieren2.simplechat W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem here. The Problem seems to be in the reimplementation of SSLParameters in Android, which you can find in your android.jar. This implementation even has a field named "endpointIdentificationAlgorithm" but is unused, so i guess it will be implemented in the future.

I did a workaround by overriding the "customize"- method which calls the missing setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm and removed the line, the rest is the original code:

```
   this.client = new WebSocketClient(new SslContextFactory(true){
        @Override
        public void customize(SSLEngine sslEngine) {
            SSLParameters sslParams = sslEngine.getSSLParameters();
            //sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(_endpointIdentificationAlgorithm);
            sslEngine.setSSLParameters(sslParams);

            if (getWantClientAuth())
                sslEngine.setWantClientAuth(getWantClientAuth());
            if (getNeedClientAuth())
                sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(getNeedClientAuth());

            sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(selectCipherSuites(
                    sslEngine.getEnabledCipherSuites(),
                    sslEngine.getSupportedCipherSuites()));

            sslEngine.setEnabledProtocols(selectProtocols(sslEngine.getEnabledProtocols(),sslEngine.getSupportedProtocols()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, I've exactly the same problem. Want to know if this workaround works fine afterall?

Comment: The workaround worked for me, but since i had other problems i now use com.neovisionaries.ws which works good for me without additional hacks